# Sorting JSON by values within the array (node.js)

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, npm

In a node.js program, I want to sort a JSON object by particular keys within the array. For example, in this JSON object I would like to sort in ascending order by the "trip_miles" value when "trip_name" equals CC, and eventually to output only the id's. So eventually the output should be 002, 003, 001. But I'm not sure how to do that kind of layered sort. Here is a [link to JSBin](https://jsbin.com/johavulefo/edit?js,console) and here is the JSON object:

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "car": "Car 1",
    "trips":[
      {
        "trip_name": "FF",
        "trip_miles": 124
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "CC",
        "trip_miles": 200
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "BB",
        "trip_miles": 204
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "DD",
        "trip_miles": 209
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "car": "Car 2",
    "trips":[
      {
        "trip_name": "AA",
        "trip_miles": 401
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "BB",
        "trip_miles": 903
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "CC",
        "trip_miles": 21
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "DD",
        "trip_miles": 439
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "car": "Car 2",
    "trips":[
      {
        "trip_name": "RR",
        "trip_miles": 300
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "QQ",
        "trip_miles": 400
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "CC",
        "trip_miles": 50
      },
      {
        "trip_name": "DD",
        "trip_miles": 60
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is what I've tried for the sorting but it's not working correctly:

```
 var sortedArray = myArray.sort(function(a,b){
      if (a.trips.trip_name == "CC" && b.trips.trip_name == "CC"){
          return a.trips.trip_miles - b.trips.trip_miles; 
      }
    })
    console.log(sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Karl Galvez explanation and here is my answer. It's better to filter out objects which do not a trip with the name "CC" before sorting. But it totally depends on the input. You do not need to worry about filtering if always all objects have a trip starts with "CC".

```
var find_trip = function(trips){
  return trips.find(trip => trip.trip_name === "CC");
}

var sorted =  myArray
  // filter out objects which does not have a trip with trip name "CC"
  .filter(obj => {
    if(find_trip(obj.trips)){
      return true;
    }
  })
  .sort(
    (a,b) => {
      return find_trip(a.trips).trip_miles - find_trip(b.trips).trip_miles;  
    }
  )
  .map(obj => obj.id)

console.log(sorted)
```

Output:

> ["002", "003", "001"]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the `myArray.sort` function will not iterate over the `trips` array in each object. You need a way to find the `"trip_name": "CC"` value so you it can be used to sort. Here is some naive code to get `myArray` sorted by the `trip_miles` of the `trip` array. It's not great, but hopefully it can get you a bit further.

```
var sortedArray = myArray.sort(function(a,b){
  const aTripCC = a.trips.filter((x) => x.trip_name === "CC");
  const bTripCC = b.trips.filter((x) => x.trip_name === "CC");

  return aTripCC[0].trip_miles - bTripCC[0].trip_miles;
})
```

Comment: It's better to check whether `aTripCC[0]` and `bTripCC[0]` objects are not undefined before accessing `trip_miles ` property. Also, you could use the find method instead of filter :)

Comment: Agreed and thanks for the comment. There's a fine line on here between being helpful and spoon feeding answers. I like to provide the highest level answer that I feel is use. The implementation details are other questions. Either way I'm glad  the question has an answer the OP feels is correct. We all in this together :)